# recursive function to find that string 1 substring of string2

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, recursive-query

i try to find a recursive function that take two string and returns true if string1 is a substring of string2 and false otherwise by check recursively if str2 starts with str1.

i try this code but it does not work i do not know why !

```
def main():
   s1 = input("enter string")
   s2 = input("enter steing")
   sub = subs(s1,s2)
   print(sub)

   def subs(s1, s2):
       if s2 == 0:
          return True
       else:
           if s2.startswith((s1)):
              subs(s1, s2[1:])
            return True 
   main()
```

thank you !

Comment: You're not returning the result of your recursive call. There may be other problems, but that's the one that jumped out at me.

Comment: Nowhere does this his return False; you may get start by addressing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has a few syntactic issues first:

1. You're invoking the `subs` function before you're actually defining it.
2. Your indent of main() is off.
3. `subs` is an inner function of `main`.  While not technically incorrect, using inner functions can make your code more difficult to read.

You also have some semantic issues:

1. `subs` is only returning true on the escape condition, there is no default return value.  This is poor practice
2. `subs` is checking if `s2 == 0`, which it will never be - strings won't equal 0.  Empty strings are Falsy, so you can check if the string is empty by using `if not s2:` instead
3. Your logic dictates that the recursion will ONLY occur if `s2` starts with `s1`, meaning if s1='ab' and s2='habc', it will not trigger recursion, even though s1 is a substring of s2.

My suggestion would be to reexamine your algorithm.  Begin with identifying how you will begin looking for a candidate substring first, then what your escape conditions are, then how you break the problem into a smaller problem.

Comment: thank you i will try to do it .. about point 3 could you please help me with the code because i try to do it many times but it is not working

Comment: OK, so you've got a good idea, you just haven't fleshed it out yet.  If s2 or s1 is empty, then we should absolutely return false, right?  Because you can't have a substring of nothing.  If that's not true, then if s2 startswith s1, then we have a substring, and we should return True.  However, if it isn't, (This is what you missed) then we should return the value of the recursive function subs with the first letter of s2 sliced off.  Does that logic make sense?  Can you translate it to code?

Comment: def subs(s1, s2):
    if s1 or s2 == "":
        return False
    else:
        for i in range (len(s2)):
            if s2.startswith((s1)):
                return True
            else:
                return(subs(s1,s2[i:]))

Comment: i write it like this but it result False in every time

Comment: @haymk unfortunately, code formatting doesn't work in comments, come to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167026/49338724 I can help you there.

Answer (score -1):

I rewrote the code you had written, but kept the intuition same. Major problems were:

1.Indentation mistakes at many places.

2.function definition after calling it.

3.Wrong method to find empty string.

```
def main():

    def subs(s1, s2,k):
        #If input string is empty .
        if k==0 and not s2.strip():
            print("Yes")
            return 0
        #String 1 not empty and search for the sub-string.
        elif s1.strip() and s1.startswith(s2):
            print("Yes")
            return 0
        #String 1 not empty and sub-string not matched.
        elif s1.strip():
            subs(s1[1:],s2,1)
        #String empty and sub-string not match.
        else :
            print("No")



    s1 = input("enter string")
    s2 = input("enter sub-string")
    sub = subs(s1,s2,0)
    #print(sub)



main()
```